# import sql dump into postgres

Tags: postgresql

when i run this command on ubuntu terminal:

```
psql -h localhost -U arwinder --password -f sh_cake_db_14_02_13.sql -d new_db
```

where "arwinder" is user name and "sh_cake_db_14_02_13.sql" is sql dump and "new_db" is database.
then while importing it shows following errors and in postgresql database I don't have all the tables. Tese are the errors:

```
invalid command \N
invalid command \
invalid command \
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "27"
LINE 1: 27 Balaji Angan
```

Comment: What is the content of the line 1 in the SQL dump?

Answer (score 0):

There is a convert tool https://github.com/lanyrd/mysql-postgresql-converter ,or you can refer to postgressql's wiki http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL , see MySQL section  and check your data types.

Comment: please explain about tool on http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqltopostgres/ link...

Comment: oh,it doesn't work.you can try this https://github.com/lanyrd/mysql-postgresql-converter

Comment: Why do you think the dump from the OP is a MySQL dump?